# How to share large number of photos for review by family, with comments saved with the pictures?

Tags: metadata, sharing, publishing

I have about 1000 old photos I need to scan and share with friends.  Before burning them to disc, though, I'd like to post them so people can comment on the provenance and/or people in the pics.  What I need for this to work efficiently is to have these comments entered as folks peruse them online, and have them automatically saved with the photos. Ultimately I want these (edited) comments saved on the disc -- so that when anyone views a pic, the comments come up with it.  Can anyone point me to an app or service that can help me with this?

Comment: You may need to be a bit more specific to help find a specific solution. To do that you may need to think about this in a few steps - Posting & collecting comments, Associating comments to its image, Presenting the image on a disc.  For example, regarding the type of disc you want, is it a CD, DVD? Is it to be read on a computer? PC? Mac? Both? Or, is the disc to be read on a DVD or Blu-Ray player attached to your TV?   In regard to presenting the images, is it like a multimedia show? cf "comments come up with". etc. - So, the more specific, the better folk can respond.

Comment: This should probably be 2 questions.  How do I collect the tags/comments and how to get them onto disc (which may be better for audio/visual than photography.SE)

Comment: 1) Posting & Collecting Comments -- I want comments that people make while perusing the photos online to be saved with the photos so that as I prepare to burn images to disc, I can easily review and edit them as appropriate. 2) Burning --  My idea was to burn the pics to DVD, and have the comments show up as essentially captions as people brought up individual pics.  But I'm open to suggestions, especially if it allows easy use of captions.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [What are the best sites to share photo galleries with friends?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/295/what-are-the-best-sites-to-share-photo-galleries-with-friends) - You haven't told us why you want to share the photos on discs. Why not just leave the photos on-line?

Comment: These pics represent the first wave of a family archive of at least 6000 photos. So the idea is that saving them to disc for distribution would allow family members to have their own copy of the archive.

Comment: I don't think your going to find software or a web site that does exactly what you want. To my knowledge, there isn't web-based "get comments first" software that can archive a library of photos to disk. There are PLENTY of ways to share photos online for comment...however you'll likely have to handle the burning of the images, and their companion comments, to disk yourself.

Comment: People flagging this question: it is clear what he is asking, and this is not a duplicate of another question. However, the request is very specialized.

Answer (score 1):

While not a trivial solution, using a WordPress gallery would allow for you to have each image displayed as a post in a gallery and you could enable commenting for each photo.  If you wanted to then embed that as meta data, you could extract the comments from the database directly.

Answer (score 1):

**Upload them all to Flickr.** The Flickr uploader is very convenient for large number of files, and they give you plenty of free space. People can then like or comment on your photos. You can also share them on Facebook and other sites directly from the Flickr website, or from the mobile app. The site is designed for exactly your purpose - sharing lots of photos at full quality.

https://www.flickr.com/

Flickr has services to produce books and other media. I don't know if Flickr comments can be included in that media, but Flickr has a programming API that can access comments, so it's possible, I just don't know if anyone has done the "auto-DVD from Flickr, with comments" app yet. However, sending DVDs isn't really a good way to do it, if your audience has internet access. A standard Flickr slide-show would give the presentation you want, and you don't have to do anything for that, it's already a feature of the site.

[How to handle publicly sharing family photos (especially kids) online?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/49067/how-to-handle-publicly-sharing-family-photos-especially-kids-online)  has some good suggestions for how to deal with privacy and sharing different sets of stuff with different people. Also some good suggestions about using other sites (Picasa, Facebook, etc)

Answer (score 0):

> I have about 1000 old photos ... I'd like to post them so people can comment on the provenance and/or people in the pics. What I need for this to work efficiently is to have these comments entered as folks peruse them online, and have them automatically saved with the photos.
>
> Ultimately I want these (edited) comments saved on the disc -- so that when anyone views a pic, the comments come up with it.

There are far more automated systems but (gasp) Facebook will do the first part well enough an the second part simply involves straight forward copying.

Facebook is free, albums can be easily made private with access either on a person by person basis (must be facebook members) or the album can be made accessible to anyone who is given the access code. Viewers can add comments as desired. By creating a dedicated page under a main facebook account photos can be divided into multiple albums with nothing except the related material visible on the site.

Maximum resolution is 2048 on the longest side.

Not everyone's most favoured image sharing site, but has its place.